# Deploying netcore web apps using ARM

Tags: .net-core, azure-rm-template, .net-core-1.1

I'm building a selection of servers with .Net core 1.1 that are grouped together in an environment and I use an ARM template to create the various Azure resources I need. Currently however I have to manually deploy the actual servers, rather than having ARM deploy the artefacts for me as I'd like.

The instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy#deploy-code-with-your-infrastructure) don't work for netcore apps, but it feels like with the move to msbuild for netcore 1.1 I should be able to do this.

I've tried searching the [quickstart ARM template repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates), but can't find anything relevant.

The biggest stumbling block seems to be that "Web Deploy for Web Apps" needs a zip file, but dotnet.exe doesn't produce one.

Answer (score 0):

you can zip the output of "dotnet publish" and use this .zip file for the deployment.

Make sure there is no root folder in the .zip. For example:

```
publish.zip
  - bunch of .dll files
  - wwwroot
  - Views
  ...
```

I hope this will help you,
KirK